# Assign property value with type conversion in Java

Tags: java, object, reflection, type-conversion

What is the best way to assign a value with type conversion to a property of an object in Java.

For eg: A Person class with age field as an integer. If the following statement has to assign integer 21 to age field, then what should be the implementation of set method? [Note: 21 is passed as string]

```
ObjectUtils.set(person, "age", "21");
```

One way is to get the type of the field and type cast explicitly. Is there any better approach or library utility available to achieve this?

Comment: If ur allowed to use 3rd party jars then BeanUtils is good in commons-beanutils.jar from Apache. otherwise you have to re-invent the wheel using Java Reflection API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [BeanUtils.setProperty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#setProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> Set the specified property value, performing type conversions as required to conform to the type of the destination property.

Comment: Apache commons always worth a look... Glad I could help :)

Comment: Perfect. Exact solution to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using [reflexion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29) you can get the attribute type dynamically, something like this:

```
Person p = ...; // The object you want to inspect
Class<?> c = p.getClass();

Field f = c.getDeclaredField("age");
f.setAccessible(true);

String typeOfAge = (String) f.getType(p);
```

After you have the attribute type its easy to cast the value.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, nice to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

use Integer.parseInt(String) in your set method. Make sure you catch the exception for an invalid number. Here is hte javadoc for parseInt

> **parseInt**
>
> **public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException** Parses the string 
>   argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string
>   must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an
>   ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value. The
>   resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and
>   the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String,
>   int) method. Parameters: s - a String containing the int
>   representation to be parsed Returns: the integer value represented by
>   the argument in decimal. Throws: NumberFormatException - if the string
>   does not contain a parsable integer.

Comment: he wants to get the type dynamically :)